# Get product attributes in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

Attributes no longer displayed after I have updated WooCommerce.

In the template `content-single-product.php` if I use `var_dump($attribute_names);` I get an array of objects.

In `foreach( $attribute_names as $attribute_name )` the scope of data is protected.

Here is the code of this template:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

<?php if($attributes) {echo "<p class='product-desc-title'>Параметры</p>";}  ?>          
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) : ?>          
<?php
    if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {
          global $post;
          $attribute_names = $attribute;

          foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
            $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );

              if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
                  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );

                  $terms_array = array();
                  $attrID = $attribute['name'];
                  $paPMat = 'pa_product-material';
                  $paPColor = 'pa_product-color';

                  // При добавлении новых атрибутов для товаров добавить новый массив с названием атрибута и слагом с приставкой "pa_"
                  $pAttributes_array = array(
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Материал фасадов',
                          'slug' => 'pa_product-material',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Цвет',
                          'slug' => 'pa_product-color',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Конфигурация',
                          'slug' => 'pa_konfiguraciya',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Материал корпуса',
                          'slug' => 'pa_material-kuxni',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Форма',
                          'slug' => 'pa_forma',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Тип дверей',
                          'slug' => 'pa_tip-dverej',
                      ),
                      array(
                          'label' => 'Створки',
                          'slug' => 'pa_stvorki',
                      ),
                array(
                          'label' => 'Размеры',
                          'slug' => 'pa_razmery',
                      ),

                  );

                  foreach ($pAttributes_array as $key => $value) {
                      if ( ! empty( $terms ) && $attrID ===  $value['slug'] ) {
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                             $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute_name );
                             $full_line = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
                             array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
                        }
                        echo '<p class="pa-string">'. $value['label'] .': '. implode( $terms_array, ',  ' ) . '</p>';
                      }
                  }
              }
          }                                                 
      } else {
          $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
          echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
      }
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: add your code to the body of the question.  link only code could become unreachable, and nullify the validity of the question.  Hence link only questions and answers may be removed by SO.

Comment: I edited your question to include your pastebin code.  It will be visible once approved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated:** Compacting your code for testing:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ):
    $attribute_names = $attribute;
    // testing output
    var_dump($attribute_name);
endforeach;
```

The `var_dump($attribute_name);` raw output gives you indications about the objects which are [`WC_Product_Attribute`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html) objects, meaning that you have to use the available methods for [this class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html).

**THERE IS 2 WAYS:**

1) You can access properties in an unprotected array using the [`get_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html#_get_data) method this way:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ):
    $attribute_data = $attribute->get_data();
    // testing pre-formatted output
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($attribute_data); echo '</pre>'; 
    // We stop the loop to get the first object only (for testing)
    break; 
endforeach;
```

That will gives you a raw output like:

```
Array (
    [id] => 1
    [name] => pa_color
    [options] => Array (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
    )
    [position] => 0
    [visible] => 
    [variation] => 1
    [is_visible] => 0
    [is_variation] => 1
    [is_taxonomy] => 1
    [value] => 
)
```

And then you can use it this way:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ):
    $attribute_data = $attribute->get_data(); // Get the data in an array

    $attribute_name = $attribute_data['name']; // The taxonomy slug name
    $attribute_terms = $attribute_data['options']; // The terms Ids
endforeach;
```

2) You can use the [`WC_Product_Attribute`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Attribute.html) methods like:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ):
    $attribute_name = $attribute->get_taxonomy(); // The taxonomy slug name
    $attribute_terms = $attribute->get_terms(); // The terms
    $attribute_slugs = $vaattributeues->get_slugs(); // The term slugs
endforeach;
```